# How can I create a file uploading site that deletes the picture when the users leaves the page?

Tags: php, image, upload, delete-file

I am on my way to create a website (PHP) where users can upload pictures to some kind of DB and when they leave the page, their pictures are deleted.
Other users (in another page) will be able to see all the pictures that are not deleted.

I thought of doing that this way:

creating a folder (lets call it 'pics') and name every picture uploaded with a number (`1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `3.jpg`, etc), when the user will leave the page the picture will delete itself (how??) and when the next one will want to upload pics, the website will search for the first number which is not taken.

If anyone has a better idea I'd like to hear it, else:

1. How can I build a function that finds the first not-taken number from a folder filled with #.jpg files only? (and what can I do to shield myself against double taking of a number)
2. How can I delete a photo when the user leaves the page?
3. How can I show a random photo from a directory?

After those will be answered: I also want the users who view the pictures to be able to click 1, 2 or 3 and to show a count of 1s 2s and 3s to the guy who uploaded the pic (who obviously still have the window open). How can I do it? (looking for a smart way without SQL db)

Idea: changing the filename to `#_1s_2s_3s.jpg` (Ex: `1_0_0_1.jpg` is pic 1 with 0,0,1 clicks) but it will make all the other questions a lot harder...

Comment: Is there any reason that you don't want it to be under a database? I'm fairly certain that SQL transactions are generally faster than disk read, which would also greatly help with the numbering system you were asking about.

Comment: added a new idea, and I maybe can do it with SQL yet I'm not sure how to? worked with SQL yet I'm not sure its the best idea for what I'm looking for (Dumping while the user is out)

Comment: in db, store file name not file...

Comment: obviously, so lets say I create a DB with: filename,1s,2s,3s,isActivated - Than I can count the nums and also to choose the random from the activated, yet - How I delete the pic and make it unactivated? (Dumb idea: refresh the page every 10seconds and write the date and time on 'isActivated' - if 15 seconds has passed, I'll look at it as unactivated. yet, how to delete it?)

Comment: I think you should learn the basics of PHP file handling http://davidwalsh.name/basic-php-file-handling-create-open-read-write-append-close-delete and improve your question by being more specific on your issue.

Comment: I know how to delete a file the things I don't know is how to execute php code when user leaves the page and how to refresh content while users is viewing the page

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's an explicit logout event (in which case the answer is easy), I'll assume that "user leaving" can only be defined in terms of "user has stopped visiting for x amount of time". I.e. it's a pretty typical session/timeout based situation. Sessions for instance operate the same way. The session timeout is extended every time the user visits another page, but is eventually cleaned out if it stayed stale for x amount of time.

I'd suggest a similar scheme for your idea:

1. On first visit, user gets a random id in a cookie, you store a database record for that id.
2. On every page load, you update a `last_seen` timestamp in the database for that user id.
3. You associate any uploaded images with that id in the database.
4. In regular intervals, you clean out any user id and its associated images if `last_seen` is older than x. This can be implemented as a cron job or as a task running more or less randomly every x page loads.

You can simply write a custom session handler which cleans out images as part of its garbage collection cycle. See http://php.net/session_set_save_handler for starters.

Comment: Thanks, as you can see I've mentioned similar idea at the comments - yet, the users stay on one page the entire time (another problem:SQL data has to update itself there) so how can I update the time stamp? new idea: maybe I'll create php files like updatetimestamp.php?id=image_id&code=image_random_generated_pass_code, #s.php?id=image_id&code=image_random_generated_pass_code

Comment: I will include those 3 in a timed loop on a js file to update the #s values, the first (updater) would be empty so I will try to open it too on the js loop (how? maybe invisible iframe or including too will work?)

Comment: If you're not going to refresh the page, you'll need to use Javascript/AJAX to ping the server every once in a while to tell it the user is still there. Other than that the idea doesn't changes from what I've described.

Comment: problem: looking for a way to included the text echoed in php file on js code